# Javascript function that should return a function becomes the function

Tags: javascript, function, closures

Long ago I've read a lot about javascript coding conventions, and one of the things I wanted to decide was the better way of declaring functions. I finally somehow stuck with the

```
var func_name = function(){};
```

version, because it seemed more useful in certain scenarios, but I wasn't really able to find things that wouldn't work the same way between them until now.

I was writing a function that should've returned a new function to be used in a setTimeout command, but I couldn't get it to work properly, and after I reduced the whole thing to this test code:

```
var test = new function(x) {
  return function() {
    if (x % 2 == 1) {
      console.log('a');
    }

    else {
      console.log('b');
    }

    x++;
  };
};
```

I happened to try if writing it in the

```
function func_name(){}
```

style would help (because I really couldn't see the problem with my code), and interestingly enough this code

```
function test(x) {
  return function() {
    if (x % 2 == 1) {
      console.log('a');
    }

    else {
      console.log('b');
    }

    x++;
  };
}
```

seems to be working perfectly.
A weird thing to discover was that after playing a bit around in the console I realized that the first one effectively becomes the function it should generate.

I tested it in Chrome and Firefox too, and I also tried using it this way

```
var test = new function(x) {
  var result = function() {
    if (x % 2 == 1) {
      console.log('a');
    }

    else {
      console.log('b');
    }

    x++;
  };

  return result;
};
```

but I wasn't able to make it work.

I would be interested in any explanation to this phenomenon and also it fascinates me if there is a way to make this type of function declaration capable of producing functions.

Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit: I don't know how, but somehow that `new` keyword got there by mistake :D (and even into the third version by that stupid copy-paste laziness of mine.....)
I'm still interested in knowing why the function becomes what it should create though!**

Comment: Don't use `new`, just use `var test = function() ...`

Comment: Thanks!!!
I don't know how I could overlook that... (I didn't intend to write it there, I don't know how that happened XD)
I'm still interested in knowing why it becomes what it should generate though1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `new`? Remove that and it should be fine IMO.

You are using it as if it were a `Construtor`.

Though valid, can create issues as your current issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know how I could overlook that... (it was kinda just like a typo, I've never messed this up before)

Comment: glad to have helped you :)